# Is it a right place to ask accessibility questions?

Tags: discussion

I’ve been struggling with solving accessibility problems lately, but can’t come with a good place to ask. It’s something between front-end development and UX design, and is probably in the middle of these disciplines.

On StackOverflow I’m afraid the questions would be lost because of enormous speed of site update’s.

From the other side, accessibility sometimes require providing implementation details like HTML/CSS code, etc.

Where would such questions be a better fit? Is ux.stackexchange fine?

Answer (score 3):

As with many UX questions - it depends.

Yes, we certainly have several accessibility questions. It's very much a big part of User Experience design.

However, it depends what sort of question you're thinking about. Bear in mind we're technology and code agnostic - we're not here to help with *how* to implement something. Our area is more focussed on *what* should be done, and we leave the actual implementation advice for other sites.

Have a look at the questions tagged [Accessibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) to get an idea of the sort of accessibility questions that work well here.